# join sublist in a list of lists with python

Tags: python, list

I am a newbie to python and have been having an issue with list comprehension. Is there a way to extend subsists in a list of list like this

`lst = [[0,0,0,0],[[x,x,x,x],[y,y,y,y]],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`

I would like to end up with a following list, but I am not sure how to approach the problem:

`lst = [[0,0,0,0],[x,x,x,x,y,y,y,y],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`

I found this snippet of code but I am not sure how to make it operate on a second "level" of lists. I tried this:

`print([x for y in lst for x in y])`
[image]

Comment: Why does your data look like this in the first place? It's simple enough to do something like write a `flatten` function and then use `[flatten(sublist) for sublist in lst]`, but it may be better to change how the data is generated so it already has the form you want.

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: imagine i am working with rectangles and i am collecting boundary lines for each thus 4 elements per. however some have a hole in them (like a doughnut) thus i end up with two 4 element lists. i want to treat those later as one, so i am trying to flatten that sublist only.

Comment: Why not just do `list1 + list2` rather than `[list1, list2]` and then trying to flatten it?

Comment: so i tried this: def flatten(l):
 reduce(lambda x,y: x.extend(y),l)
new_lst = [flatten(sublist) for sublist in lst] it doesnt quite work.

Comment: also that list is a product of a function that i had to run on it to even get the boundary lines. there is nothing that i can do to prevent it from generating like that. it is what it is...i just need a little help flattening it like i asked so i can move on to the next thing. please, and thank you.

Comment: From the image, it seems like there is one additional list encapsulated in your list, `[[[0, 0, 0, 0]], [[[3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2]]], [[0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0]]]`, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Just go through each element and if it has a length of 2 (which means its a donut), add the two elements of that sublist together.

```
def flatten(data):
    new_data = [lists[0]+lists[1] if len(lists) == 2 else lists for lists in data]
    return new_data

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
new_data = flatten(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, you can do as follows:

```
x,y=1,2
lst = [[0,0,0,0],[[x,x,x,x],[y,y,y,y]],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

map(lambda l: sum(l,[]) if isinstance(l[0],list) else l, lst)

#gives: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I assumed that `x=1`, and `y=2`.

Based on the image, it seems you have nested lists in the following way:

```
x,y=1,2
lst = [[[0,0,0,0]],[[[x,x,x,x],[y,y,y,y]]],[[0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0]]]
# 0, x, and y in you case are lists/touples, but for this example there are ints.
# it should not matter anyway for this example.

map(lambda l: [sum(l[0],[])] if len(l[0])==2 else l, lst)
# relults in: [[[0, 0, 0, 0]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]], [[0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Marcin, I think yours is the closest one, however, I think i might have made a mistake explaining it. I attached an image of what I am getting and what part i want to flatten.

Comment: another version for this solution, `[sum(sublist, []) if isinstance(sublist[0], type(list)) else sublist for sublist in lst]`

Comment: Marcin, I was just reading up on a use of lambda functions. They look really powerful. Now, your solution makes a lot more sense to me, it looked a little scary at first. One more thing that I am wondering about is the Sum(l[0],[]) which i understand as combine contents of index 0 with remaining indexes if they equal 2. Can I change that to !=1 if I am anticipating to have more than [0] and [1] thus len() might return more than 2? would that fool proof it?

Comment: @konrad yep, if you set `len(l[0])!=1` it might not work because the length of sub-lists in your example image is either 2 (which should be concatenated) or 4 (which are ok). Thus, they only thing I can recommend is try and see approach. It really depends on your data.